# why is l { xy | x,y in {a, b}* ,where |x| = |y| } regular? Supposedly it is just even length strings?

Tags: regular-language

So can someone explain {xy | x,y \in {a, b}* , |x| = |y|} regular. Apparently the answer is it is just even length strings but I can't see why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

The language L = {xy | x,y in {a, b}* , |x| = |y|} is exactly the language of words of even length:

1. Every word of even length is in L: If w in {a,b}* is even, then there is some natural number k, such that |w| = 2*k. Therefore, w can be split into two words of length k, so there are x,y in {a,b}* such that w = xy and |x| = |y| = k. Therefore, w is in L.
2. Every word in L is of even length: Consider w in L. Then by definition of L, there are x,y in {a,b}* , such that |x| = |y| and w = xy. Therefore |w| = |xy| = |x| + |y| = 2*|x|. Therefore, w is of even length.

Next, you have to show L is regular. You could do this by constructing a DFA with two states q0 and q1, where q0 is the starting state and also accepting. From q0, reading a or b takes you to q1, and from q1, reading a or b takes you back to q0. Then the words for which a run of the automaton ends in q0 are exactly the words of even length.